# Auto-Snap a Terminal (or Nautilus) when Opened

Tags: unity, nautilus, gnome-terminal, 15.10

Like 98% of the time I open a Terminal or Nautilus, I want to use it snapped to the right/left... especially if I am using more than one instance of them.

Can I configure my Ubuntu to open any instance of Nautilus or Terminal in 'snapped' mode?

I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: It seems to kinda solve my problem, but it also appears to be a little to much or me. Since Ubuntu is already capable of positioning a window as snapped left or right why do I have to use different code.
What does Ubuntu use in the background if I use CTRL+Windows+Left/Right.
Can I extend this script with this utilized routine.

Comment: Most likely not, since the commands are not available as separate "external" command line options of Unity or Compiz. You *could* simulate the key combination when the window appears, but it would still need a script to wait for the window and synchronize it , *and* it would be too dirty imo, since it would snap the wrong window if you switch windows in between.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am currently struggling with, too..

Comment: The script is not the problem, synchronizing neither. Dirty or not, give it a shot?

Comment: The little thing the text mentioned about a little offset between the borders and the actual windows may drive me crazy, but I will give it a shot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could use is the `-geometry` option for `nautilus` shortcut.

For instance, I could set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (which is same as Windows shortcut for opening "My Computer" ) to `nautilus --geometry 250x250+0+0` . The `geometry` option is defined in `man X` page as `WIDTH+HEIGHT+XOFFSET+YOFFSET`.  +/- can be used and `man` page defines the corners as:

+0+0    upper left hand corner.

-0+0    upper right hand corner.

-0-0    lower right hand corner.

+0-0    lower left hand corner.

With terminal , that's a little different because `gnome-terminal` treats geometry option as in rows by columns. So `gnome-terminal`--geometry="250x250+0+0"` will open a window that is just horribly large.

What you also could do is to alter the `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` folder, particularly the `Exec=` line to have the geometry option, so that launcher icons also  can spawn windows with specific size

Comment: In addition on a 1902x1080 display, I found ``gnome-terminal --geometry 101x56+0+0`` to be the perfect fit

Answer (score 0):

You could install the Compiz Config Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-config-settings-manager
```

Run it from Dash and then under the Window Manager heading you should find options that let you customize how you want to mange your windows.